# Remove event listener vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a special scenario described as short as possible in this pen: http://codepen.io/tuelsch/pen/rVRRNm?editors=101

This article ([Adding and Removing Event Listeners with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088010/adding-and-removing-event-listeners-with-parameters)) pointed me in the right direction but has a different setup.

I like to have a custom JS object (Film) which can add and remove event handler on its `link` property (a DOM element).

I'm stuck with the `removeEvent` function on line 18. What is the correct second argument for the `removeEventListener` function in this case?

Instead of adding and removing the event listener, it just keeps adding event listeners, as can be observed in the console, where the result of line 8 is logged.

The solution should be plain vanilla JavaScript, ES5 compatible and intended to run in the browser (IE9+).

Comment: you remove an event listener with the **exact** same arguments as you add event listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can first keep the record of that binded event in your object like:

```
// Add the event handler
Film.prototype.bindEvent = function () {
  // This ensure that the binded event can be removed by removeEvent
  // even if you call bindEvent many times.
  if (!this._bindedEvent) {
    this._bindedEvent = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
    this.link.addEventListener('click', this._bindedEvent);
  }
}
```

Then remove that:

```
// Remove the event handler
Film.prototype.removeEvent = function () {
  if (this._bindedEvent) {
    this.link.removeEventListener('click', this._bindedEvent); 
    this._bindedEvent = null;
  }
}
```

2 . Another way is to override `eventhandler` in constructor:

```
// The test class definition
var Film = function () {
  this.link = document.getElementById('film');
  // This first find if self has attr eventHandler, and keep lookup to its prototype.
  // Then createa binded version of eventhandler and set to this's attr.
  // So when you try to access `this.eventHandler`, it'll be the binded version instead of Prototype's
  this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
}
```

Then you can just use

```
// Add the event handler
Film.prototype.bindEvent = function () {
    this.link.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler);
}

// Remove the event handler
Film.prototype.removeEvent = function () {
    this.link.removeEventListener('click', this.eventHandler); 
}
```

To add and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.bind(this)` as you do here: `this.link.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler.bind(this));` you actually get a new function. When you try to remove it, you use the original handler, and the remove can't find the binded handler.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

To fix that use the bind when you define the handler ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvmmRw?editors=101) - the handler is removed after 3 seconds):

```
// The event handler to add and remove
Film.prototype.eventHandler = function () {
  console.log('handled');
}.bind(Film);

// Add the event handler
Film.prototype.bindEvent = function () {
  this.link.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler);
}

// Remove the event handler
Film.prototype.removeEvent = function () {
  this.link.removeEventListener('click', this.eventHandler);
}
```

Comment: Now `this` is the window, and no longer the current instance of `Film`, which would be needed inside the event handler.

Comment: Thanks @phippu - fixed.

Comment: While I like the simplicity of the code, it did not work for me, because inside the eventHandler, `this` is a reference to the constructor function, and not the instanciated object.

Comment: The this of the constructor function is the this of the instantiated object, because if it wasn't all instances would have the same properties. However,  I would like to know why it didn't work, so I'll create a demo later, and post it.