# Add an event listener with parameters and then remove it

Tags: javascript

### The basic scenario

This question has been asked before. In fact, it's been asked [with nearly the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088010/adding-and-removing-event-listeners-with-parameters) but please stick with me for a moment, I don't think the question has a good answer yet.

So, we have an event listener:

```
fancyButton.addEventListener('click', this.launchKitty, true);
```

And then we have a function:

```
// assume this.setForLaunch was set somewhere
launchKitty = () => {
  if(this.setForLaunch){ // behold, this!
    console.log('farewell, feline!')
  }
}
```

We have an event listener and a function with access to the outer `this`, which is neat. Removal is easy:

```
fancyButton.removeEventListener('click', this.launchKitty, true);
```

But what if we didn't want to use `this`?

### Parameters!

What if, instead of leaning on `this`, we wanted to pass `addEventListener` an argument? Like so:

```
fancyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {this.launchKitty(true)}, true);
```

And a slightly modified `launchKitty()`:

```
launchKitty(setForLaunch) {
  if(setForLaunch){ // now we're using a parameter!
    console.log('farewell, feline!')
  }
}
```

So far, so good. Kitties are launched. What about removing the listener?

```
fancyButton.removeEventListener('click', () => {this.launchKitty}, true);
```

Not going to work. Our `() => {}` is anonymous and therefore `removeEventListener` doesn't know how to find it.

### The question

How can we pass an event listener a parameter and then later remove said event handler?

Please feel free to challenge any of my assumptions. There are a lot of ways to launch this cat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the currently anonymous function into a variable, so that you can call `removeEventListener` with it later:

```
const launchKittyTrue = () => { this.launchKitty(true) };
fancyButton.addEventListener('click', launchKittyTrue, true);
// later:
fancyButton.removeEventListener('click', launchKittyTrue, true);
```

To be more flexible, you might consider a `Map` indexed by arguments, whose values are the bound functions:

```
const boundFns = new Map();
function makeListener(arg) {
  if (!boundFns.has(arg)) {
    boundFns.set(arg, launchKitty.bind(undefined, arg));
  }
  return boundFns.get(arg);
}
function getListener(arg) {
  return boundFns.get(arg);
}
fancyButton.addEventListener('click', makeListener(true), true);
// later:
fancyButton.removeEventListener('click', getListener(true), true);
```

Comment: This is a really interesting solution, but it would be constrained to a limited set of parameters. My example did use `setForLaunch=true` (so legit answer), but what if  `setForLaunch='french-fry'`, or any other string, was also valid?

Comment: The `Map` solution will take care of that - it'll work properly with any single argument, no matter its type. Additional arguments would be a pain, I suppose a recursive set of `Map`s would be a possibility though

Comment: If all arguments are primitives, you could also use `JSON.stringify`/`parse` rather than recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @CertainPerformance's answer. You can use the bind method from the Function prototype to instantiate a 'copy' of the function with parameters bound to it.

Something like:

```js
function launchKitty(setForLaunch) {
  console.log(`launchKitty called with setForLaunch = ${setForLaunch}`);
}

let fancyTrue = launchKitty.bind(null, true);
let fancyFalse = launchKitty.bind(null, false);

let fancyButton = document.getElementById('fancyButton');
let lessFancyButton = document.getElementById('lessFancyButton');
let detachButton =  document.getElementById('detachFancyButton');

fancyButton.addEventListener('click', fancyTrue, true);

lessFancyButton.addEventListener('click', fancyFalse, true);


detachButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fancyButton.removeEventListener('click', fancyTrue, true);
  lessFancyButton.removeEventListener('click', fancyFalse, true);
});
```

```html
<button id='fancyButton'>Console Log</button>
<button id='lessFancyButton'>No Console Log</button>

<button id='detachFancyButton'>Detach Handlers</button>
```