# Removing EventListeners with parameters

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to remove an event listener with parameters.
I've understood that passing arguments when assigning a listener wouldn't work, so I finally worked a way to remove the arguments for the listener assignment. But it still not working.

I'm really not sure where to look next.

**Here is the code (I have removed everything that has nothing to do with the issue)**

```
let activeItemOnTheMove = false;

activeItem.addEventListener('click', e=>{   

    const defineOnMouseMove = () => { onMouseMove(activeItem) };

    if(!activeItemOnTheMove){
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', defineOnMouseMove);
        activeItemOnTheMove = true;
    }else{
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', defineOnMouseMove);
        activeItemOnTheMove = false;
    }
})



function onMouseMove(activeItem){           
    activeItem.style.position ='absolute';
    activeItem.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
    activeItem.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
    activeItem.style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
}
```

(I am using vanilla javascript)

I have read these answers, this is how I understood that I couldn't use an anonymous function. But I am not sure I understand the fundamental of why it doesn't work.

- [Adding and Removing Event Listeners with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088010/adding-and-removing-event-listeners-with-parameters)
- [Add an event listener with parameters and then remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058903/add-an-event-listener-with-parameters-and-then-remove-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Javascript removeEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working)

Comment: (On SO, we don't fold answers into questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is how I understood that I couldn't use an anonymous function

It doesn't matter whether the function is anonymous or not. What matters is using the **same** function with both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. Your code isn't doing that, it's using a new function with `removeEventListener`, which doesn't do anything because that function isn't registered as an event listener (it's just that a different function with the same code in it is).

Since you have to remember the function, you can use that variable as your flag as well if you like:

```
let activeMouseMoveHandler = null; // *** A variable to remember the function in

activeItem.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!activeMouseMoveHandler) {
        activeMouseMoveHandler = () => { onMouseMove(activeItem) };
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", activeMouseMoveHandler);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", activeMouseMoveHandler);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I managed to make it work !!! (by changing defineOnMouseMove by activeMouseMoveHandler) 
But I have a hard time understanding why is it different?

The only difference I can make of it is that you first declare activeMouseMoveHandler , then assign the function to it, instead of assigning it directly.  What is the difference between the two methods? 
You also say that the issue is that it isn't registering as an event listener, but where does it do that in your example?

Again thank you for your answer!

Comment: (I've edited the answer with the working code)

Comment: @TryingVlad - Sorry about that, it was just an editing error. It should be `activeMouseMoveHandler` throughout. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: I just realised that I was redefining the function each time I was clicking on the item.  All is clear now. Thank you !